# Is using the first person in a résumé really that bad?

Tags: resume, job-search

I have been told that using first-person pronouns in a résumé is bad form. It is suggested usually to drop pronouns altogether. I feel awkward writing in this disjointed form, however.

My résumé has always been written with "I", "me", and "my" used throughout. Is this actually as bad as I've been told, or does it come down to tradition?

Comment: I don't even think it's tradition. It's style, and not universally agreed upon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A resume is a (theoretically) factual presentation about yourself, it's not correspondence. I would keep the first-person pronouns in the cover letter and let the resume be a reference document that speaks **about you** as opposed to being **from you**.

Answer (score 2):

Heh. Like your style.

Resumes without personal pronouns

- are to the point
- this increases the chance of being read fully
- pertinent information stands out more, rather than pronoun "fluff"
- read more authoritatively. pronoun's present information as "opinion"

When i write a resume with personal pronouns, the tendency is to write on a bit more. Ah, I guess what I'm saying is that suddenly it reads more like a novel - a very, very boring novel, unless you're a lobster fisherman or a spy. I don't think either profession has much interest in resumes though. I know it is less *fun* to write this way, but it will help you get your point across - personal pronouns are best left for the cover letter.

- i've often felt that when i make a point using personal pronouns, the space they take up gets in the way of the point
- also, the "i" is redundant, because of *course* the resume is about the writer, who else would it be about?
- i don't think you'd be *explicitly* penalized for having an "i" in the resume, i just think you'd be needlessly hindering your chances.
- oh, and i reckon that with the pronouns i come across less "can-do" and more "philosopher", which might be a hindrance unless you're applying for a role in a philosophy... uh, thing?